# Comparing DoublyLinkedList<T> implementation performance with other BCL (.NET) classes

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have implemented generic doubly-linked list class, which supports `IEnumerable<T>`,`IEnumerator<T>` interfaces.

`DoublyLinkedList<T>` is fully compatible with standart BCL classes.

Targets:

- class can be used as a standard replacement for `Stack<T>`, `Queue<T>` and `List<T>`.
- class itself is *immutable*, so you can-not change the containing value of the element.
- class methods raises exceptions which conforms for common considerations.
- class method's `lock` statement was used for locking current *active* element.
- class *Push*, *Pop*, *Peek* operations is breaking the current state of the enumerated object.

How can we compare the performance for that class compared to the BCL classes and other implementation?

Will you provide the C# code to compare to the BCL classes like `Stack<T>`, `Querty<T>`, `List<T>`?

Unit tests (code coverage - 100%):

```
[TestClass]
public class DoublyLinkedListUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestValueMethod()
    {
        DoublyLinkedList<int> dll = new DoublyLinkedList<int>();

        int i1 = 1;
        int i2 = 2;
        int i3 = 3;

        Assert.AreEqual(((IDoublyLinkedList<int>)dll).Index, -1);
        try
        {
            dll.Peek();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        using (IEnumerator<int> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.MoveLast(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.MovePrevious(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, default(int));
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 0);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, -1);

            try
            {
                dll.Pop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }

            dll.Add(i1);
            dll.MovePrevious();
            try
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }
            dll.MoveLast();
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i1);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 0);

            dll.Add(i2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 1);

            dll.MoveFirst();
            try
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }
            try
            {
                dll.Add(i1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }
            dll.MoveLast();

            dll.Add(i3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 2);
        }

        IEnumerator o = ((IEnumerable)dll).GetEnumerator();
        o.MoveNext();
        Assert.AreEqual(o.Current, i1);

        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        dll.CopyTo(list);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.ToList().Except(list).Count(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(list.Except(dll).Count(), 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(list.Count, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[0], i1);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[1], i2);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[2], i3);

        using (IEnumerator<int> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i1);

            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), false);

            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            dll.Remove();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        dll.AddRange(list);
        try
        {
            dll.AddRange(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ArgumentNullException), ex.GetType());
        }
        try
        {
            dll.MoveFirst();
            dll.AddRange(list);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(i1), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(i2), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(i3), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(default(int)), false);

        using (IEnumerator<int> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i1);

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i2);

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, i3);
        }

        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(i3);
        stack.Push(i2);
        stack.Push(i1);
        foreach (object value in dll)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(stack.Pop(), value);
        }

        try
        {
            int value = default(int);
            while ((value = dll.Pop()) != default(int))
            {
                stack.Push(value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        dll.Push(i1);
        dll.Push(i2);
        dll.Push(i3);
        dll.Clear();
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.MoveFirst(), false);

        stack.Clear();
        stack.Push(i3);
        stack.Push(i2);
        stack.Push(i1);
        foreach (int value in stack)
        {
            dll.Push(value);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Peek(), value);
        }

        IDoublyLinkedList<int> dllInterface = dll;
        dllInterface.Reset();

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), false);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, default(int));
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, -1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i2);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i3);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveFirst(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveLast(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i3);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i2);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, i1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, default(int));
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, -1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestReferenceMethod()
    {
        DoublyLinkedList<object> dll = new DoublyLinkedList<object>();

        object o1 = new object();
        object o2 = new object();
        object o3 = new object();

        Assert.AreEqual(((IDoublyLinkedList<object>)dll).Index, -1);
        try
        {
            dll.Peek();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        using (IEnumerator<object> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.MoveLast(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.MovePrevious(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), false);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, default(object));
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 0);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, -1);

            try
            {
                dll.Pop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }

            dll.Add(o1);
            dll.MovePrevious();
            try
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }
            dll.MoveLast();
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o1);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 0);

            dll.Add(o2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 2);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 1);

            dll.MoveFirst();
            try
            {
                dll.Add(o1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
            }
            dll.MoveLast();

            dll.Add(o3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Count, 3);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.CurrentIndex, 2);
        }

        IEnumerator o = ((IEnumerable)dll).GetEnumerator();
        o.MoveNext();
        Assert.AreEqual(o.Current, o1);

        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        dll.CopyTo(list);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.ToList().Except(list).Count(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(list.Except(dll).Count(), 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(list.Count, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[0], o1);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[1], o2);
        Assert.AreEqual(list[2], o3);

        using (IEnumerator<object> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o1);

            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), false);

            if (dll.Count > 0)
            {
                dll.Remove();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            dll.Remove();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        dll.AddRange(list);
        try
        {
            dll.AddRange(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ArgumentNullException), ex.GetType());
        }
        try
        {
            dll.MoveFirst();
            dll.AddRange(list);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(o1), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(o2), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(o3), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.Contains(default(object)), false);

        using (IEnumerator<object> dllEnumerator = dll.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o1);

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o2);

            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.MoveNext(), true);
            Assert.AreEqual(dllEnumerator.Current, o3);
        }

        Stack<object> stack = new Stack<object>();
        stack.Push(o3);
        stack.Push(o2);
        stack.Push(o1);
        foreach (object value in dll)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(stack.Pop(), value);
        }

        try
        {
            object value = default(object);
            while ((value = dll.Pop()) != default(object))
            {
                stack.Push(value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ex.GetType());
        }

        dll.Push(o1);
        dll.Push(o2);
        dll.Push(o3);
        dll.Clear();
        Assert.AreEqual(dll.MoveFirst(), false);

        stack.Clear();
        stack.Push(o3);
        stack.Push(o2);
        stack.Push(o1);
        foreach (object value in stack)
        {
            dll.Push(value);
            Assert.AreEqual(dll.Peek(), value);
        }

        IDoublyLinkedList<object> dllInterface = dll;
        dllInterface.Reset();

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), false);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, default(object));
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, -1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o2);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveNext(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o3);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveFirst(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MoveLast(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o3);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o2);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 1);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, o1);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, 0);

        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.MovePrevious(), true);
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.Current, default(object));
        Assert.AreEqual(dllInterface.CurrentIndex, -1);            
    }
}
```

Source code:

```
public interface IDoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator, IEnumerable, IDisposable
{
    void Add(T value);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> values);
    bool Contains(T item);
    void Remove();
    bool MoveFirst();
    bool MovePrevious();
    bool MoveLast();
    void CopyTo(List<T> list);
    List<T> ToList();
    void Clear();
    T Pop();
    T Peek();
    void Push(T value);
    int Count { get; }
    int Index { get; }
    int CurrentIndex { get; }
}

public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IDoublyLinkedList<T>
{
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> _current;
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> _previous;
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> _first;
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> _last;
    private readonly T _value;
    private readonly int _count;

    public DoublyLinkedList()
    {
        _current = this;
    }
    private DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList<T> copy)
    {
        _current = copy;
        _previous = copy._previous;
        _first = copy._first;
        _last = copy._last;
        _count = copy._count;
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_current)
            {
                if (_last != null)
                {
                    return _last._count;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_current)
            {
                return _count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    public int CurrentIndex
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_current)
            {
                return _current._count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    private DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList<T> previous, T value)
    {
        _current = this;
        _previous = previous;
        _value = value;
        _count = previous._count + 1;
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        _current = this;
        _previous = null;
        _first = null;
        _last = null;
    }
    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            foreach (T value in this)
            {
                if (object.Equals(value, item))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void CopyTo(List<T> list)
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            list.AddRange(this);
        }
    }
    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            return new List<T>(this);
        }
    }
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (values != null)
            {
                if (_current._first == null)
                {
                    foreach (T value in values)
                    {
                        _current._first = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(_current, value);
                        _current = _current._first;
                    }
                    _last = _current;
                    return;
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
    public void Add(T value)
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_current._first == null)
            {
                _current._first = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(_current, value);
                _last = _current = _current._first;
                return;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
    public void Remove()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_current._first == null)
            {
                if (_current._previous != null)
                {
                    _last = _current = _current._previous;
                    _current._first = null;
                    return;
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
    public T Pop()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_last != null)
            {
                _current = _last;
            }
            if (_current._previous != null)
            {
                T value = _current._value;
                _last = _current = _current._previous;
                _current._first = null;
                return value;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
    public T Peek()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_last != null)
            {
                _current = _last;
            }
            if (_current._previous != null)
            {
                T value = _current._value;
                return value;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
    public void Push(T value)
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_last != null)
            {
                _current = _last;
            }
            _current._first = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(_current, value);
            _last = _current = _current._first;
        }
    }
    public bool MoveFirst()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_first != null)
            {
                _current = _first;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool MoveLast()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_last != null)
            {
                _current = _last;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool MovePrevious()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_current._previous != null)
            {
                _current = _current._previous;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    T IEnumerator<T>.Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_current)
            {
                return _current._value;
            }
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            return new DoublyLinkedList<T>(this);
        }
    }
    bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            if (_current._first != null)
            {
                _current = _current._first;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_current)
            {
                return _current._value;
            }
        }
    }
    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            _current = this;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_current)
        {
            return new DoublyLinkedList<T>(this);
        }
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: As an observation, your unit tests don't seem to be testing... a unit of work.  It's testing the entire swath of functionality of the class, once for value types and once for reference types.  I would recommend breaking them up into smaller, more granular tests which hit upon each area of functionality.  A quick rule-of-thumb would be one operation, one assert per test.  I'm going to post an answer with a short example of this.

Comment: _"Will you provide the C# code to compare to the BCL classes like Stack<T>, Querty<T>, List<T>?"_ ... That's [not what Code Review is for](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

More granular unit tests as per my comment above.

```
    [TestClass]
    public sealed class DoublyLinkedListUnitTest
    {
        private IDoublyLinkedList<int> valueDll;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllInitialize()
        {
            this.valueDll = new DoublyLinkedList<int>();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllIndex()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, this.valueDll.Index);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllPeek()
        {
            var intValue = this.valueDll.Peek();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllMoveLast()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(false, this.valueDll.MoveLast());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllMovePrevious()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(false, this.valueDll.MovePrevious());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllEnumeratorMoveNext()
        {
            using (var dllEnumerator = this.valueDll.GetEnumerator())
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(false, dllEnumerator.MoveNext());
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllEnumeratorCurrent()
        {
            using (var dllEnumerator = this.valueDll.GetEnumerator())
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(default(int), dllEnumerator.Current);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllCount()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(0, this.valueDll.Count);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllCurrentIndex()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, this.valueDll.CurrentIndex);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllPop()
        {
            var intValue = this.valueDll.Pop();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestEmptyValueDllAdd()
        {
            const int I1 = 1;

            this.valueDll.Add(I1);
            this.TestEmptyValueDllIndex();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, this.valueDll.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, this.valueDll.CurrentIndex);

            var i1 = this.valueDll.Peek(); // Technically not a "unit" test since we are relying on Peek() to work too.

            Assert.AreEqual(I1, i1);
        }

        //// Add more unit tests here.
    }
}
```